# jquery tablesorter both asc and desc from a single external link

Tags: tablesorter

I want to sort both asc and desc direction alternately from the link 
Not from the table header
I am not able to figure it out, the code that inserted is working only one direction. I need both directions

plugin :: jQuery plugin:Tablesorter2.0

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border=1> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tbody>

<a id="trigger-link" href="#">I want to sort both asc and des`enter code here`c alternately from this link</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
$("#trigger-link").click(function() { 
var sorting = [[0,1]]; 
$("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
return false; 
});
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you now have two ways to accomplish this:

1. Trigger a "sort" event on the header cell (v2.9+)

   ```
   $("table").find("th:contains(Discount)").trigger("sort");
   ```
2. As of v2.17.0, you can trigger the "sorton" method using an "n" (or next) variable

   ```
   $("table").trigger("sorton", [ [[0,"n"]] ]);
   ```

Please see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-trigger-sort.html) for other sort methods.